# Determining when the hypersurface is smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $S_{a_1, \cdots, a_n}\subseteq\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, $a_1, \cdots, a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ be the hypersurface

\begin{eqnarray}S_{a_1, \cdots, a_n}=\left\{(z_1, \cdots, z_{n+1})\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\left|\ z_k=\sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n}x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}-\binom{n}{k}\text{ for }1\leq k\leq n, z_{n+1}=x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}-1, x_i\in\mathbb{C}\right.\right\}\end{eqnarray}

What is the polynomial $p(z_1, \cdots, z_{n+1})$ which vanishes on $S_{a_1, \cdots, a_n}$? In particular, what conditions does the integer $n$-tuples $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ have to satisfy in order that $S_{a_1, \cdots, a_n}$ is smooth at the origin? I know that if (1)$a_1=1$, $a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$, (2)$a_1=\cdots=a_{n-1}=1$, $a_n=0$, (3)$a_1=\cdots=a_{n}=1$,  or (4) $n=4$, $a_1=a_2=1$, $a_3=a_4=0$, the hypersurfaces in those cases are all hyperplanes and hence smooth at the origin.